# add invoice items works with stripe SDK but not Laravel cashier

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

Im trying to get this working with laravel so i can do a one time charge together with a subscription.

**The code that works.**
**Stripe SDK way**

```
        \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create([
        'email' => $request->email,
    ]);

    $paymentMethod = \Stripe\PaymentMethod::retrieve($request->token);

    $paymentMethod->attach([
        'customer' => $customer->id,
    ]);

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::update($customer->id, [
        'invoice_settings' => [
            'default_payment_method' => $paymentMethod->id,
        ],
    ]);

    $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
        'customer' => $customer->id,
        'items' => [
            [
                'plan' => $request->plan,
            ],
        ],
        'add_invoice_items' => [
            ['price' => 'PRICE_ID']
        ],

        'off_session' => true, //for use when the subscription renews
    ]);
```

**The code that dont work.**
**Laravel cashier way**

```
        $subscription = $request->user()->newSubscription('default', $request->plan);

    $subscription->create($request->token, [
        'email' => $request->email,
    ], [
            'add_invoice_items' => [
                [
                    'price' => 'PRICE_ID'
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

**Conclusion**

If there is no way for me to get this working with laravel cashier / Billable.
Then i need to use the SDK and then i need to handle a lot of other things manually like saving the recently created customer in my own DB. Cashier handles all these things for you. Is there really not a way to add simple stripe options to cashier?

Comment: what is the error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using [Laravel Cashier](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing).

```
$subscription = $user->newSubscription('default', [
    $subscription->id,
])->create($request->payment_method, [], [
    'add_invoice_items' => [
        ['price' => $product->id]
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have not specified your error ! I guess you need to bypass the laravel's csrf protection. I've done that previously when I implemented stripe using cashier once.

go to App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken and add 'stripe/*' inside the except array

```
protected $except = [
    'stripe/*',
];
```

check for the reference: [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing)